# How to keep track of the return data from entry widgets in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I create 2 entry boxes and user will type the data in. I bind the entry box with Tab key. After entry1 is filled then user presses Tab key to move to the next entry box (entry2). I want the data in entry1 will be checked against min and max those are set specifically for entry box 1 and 2 as soon as the Tab key is pressed. If entry1 is fail then the msg_box will be pop up. If all pass then the data will be sent to the database. How to determine that the data after Tab key is pressed is belong to which entry box so that it can be checked? cause user after press tab can go back to edit the data.
Here is my simple code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import StringVar

main_wd = tkinter.Tk()
my_var1 = StringVar()
my_var2 = StringVar()


def enter(event, var):
    print(var.get())
    

entry1 = tkinter.Entry(main_wd, textvariable = my_var1)
entry1.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
entry1.bind('<Tab>', lambda event: enter(event, var=my_var1))


entry2 = tkinter.Entry(main_wd, textvariable = my_var2)
entry2.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
entry2.bind('<Tab>', lambda event: enter(event, var=my_var2))
main_wd.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't understand what your end goal is? What is it about your code that does not work?

Comment: `Entry` widgets don't return the text you write in them. You have to either trace it, connect a variable, or manually retrieve it.

Comment: Whats wrong with the code you gave?

Comment: I don't know data printed out belong to which entry box. In the code if you press Tab the data will be printed out. And you press Tab again the data from entry 2 will be printed out. That is easy.

Comment: What else do you want?

Comment: I don't know data printed out belong to which entry box. In the code if you press Tab the data will be printed out. And you press Tab again the data from entry 2 will be printed out. That is easy. Now if you have the tolerance for entry 1 is +- 0.005 and entry 2 is +-0.003 So after entry 1 is filled user will press Tap key. The enter function will return the data for entry 1 and it will be checked against the tolerance 1. If pass data will change to green, fail red. The process will be the same for entry 2. So if after filling up two entry boxes the user goes back and edit entry 1 press Tab?

Comment: Let say they edit entry box 1 then press Tab. How can I get that data to check with tolerance 1?

Comment: Sorry cause the comment limit letters..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the limits into your function the same way you pass the stringvar in.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import StringVar

main_wd = tkinter.Tk()
my_var1 = StringVar()
my_var2 = StringVar()

def enter(event, var, start, end):
    print(var.get())
    if int(var.get()) > end:
        print('var is too big!')
    elif int(var.get()) < start:
        print('var is too small!')

entry1 = tkinter.Entry(main_wd, textvariable = my_var1)
entry1.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
entry1.bind('<Tab>', lambda event: enter(event, var=my_var1, start=5, end=10))

entry2 = tkinter.Entry(main_wd, textvariable = my_var2)
entry2.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
entry2.bind('<Tab>', lambda event: enter(event, var=my_var2, start=100, end=200))
main_wd.mainloop()
```

However this really sounds like a good place to use a subclass:

```
import tkinter

class VanN(tkinter.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master=None, start=None, end=None, **kwargs):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.var = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.config(textvariable=self.var)
        self.bind('<Tab>', self.enter)

    def enter(self, event=None):
        value = int(self.var.get())
        print(value)
        if self.end is not None and value > self.end:
            print('var is too big!')
        elif self.start is not None and value < self.start:
            print('var is too small!')

main_wd = tkinter.Tk()

entry1 = VanN(main_wd, start=5, end=10)
entry1.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

entry2 = VanN(main_wd, start=100, end=200)
entry2.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

main_wd.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think OP wants to set focus back to the wrong entry too.

Comment: Thank you so much Novel. That is what I need. Now I know where to set the data range (tolerance) in.

Comment: It is not clear to me why not using validate command when focusing out?

Comment: @FlavioMoraes the validate command would function differently than what OP described, not allowing the entry instead of pop up error. However it may work for OP so I encourage you to add an answer to show that.

Comment: Hi Novel, I really like the class that you've created. I can use a loop to create a series entry boxes easily. But if I want to delete all data in all entry boxes what parameters and how to pass them into the delete function. (let say I create a button RESET and a delete function). Thanks

Comment: I found  a solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Novel I'm adding a new answer to show you how to do the same thing using `validatecommand` instead of binding an event to the `Entry`. The tkinter Entry `validatecommand` attribute defines a method to call to check if content is valid. In your case we also want to define `validate` as `focusout` so the checking method will be called when you click outside the Entry or press TAB. It is important to know that the method must return `True` or `False` if you accept or reject the input.

Bellow is the same answer of Novel but using `validatecommand` instead. I also added a `try/finally` in case user leave the entry without type anything:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import StringVar

main_wd = tkinter.Tk()
my_var1 = StringVar()
my_var2 = StringVar()

def enter(var, start, end):
    print(var.get())
    try:
        if int(var.get()) > end:
            print('var is too big!')
            return False
        elif int(var.get()) < start:
            print('var is too small!')
            return False
    finally:
        return True
    

entry1 = tkinter.Entry(main_wd, textvariable = my_var1, validate='focusout', validatecommand=lambda: enter(my_var1, 5, 10))
entry1.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

entry2 = tkinter.Entry(main_wd, textvariable = my_var2, validate='focusout', validatecommand=lambda: enter(my_var2, 100, 200))
entry2.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

main_wd.mainloop()
```